# method of characteristics for first order PDE: theory on existence and uniqueness

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have been looking for this for years now. I can apply the method and understand the ideas behind it, but I want theoretic results on existence and uniqueness, textbooks omit them, it seems. Can someone please point me to a good source? This article https://www.kth.se/social/files/560a55b6f276543ece51692f/Lectures_Method_of_Characteristics.pdf looked promising, but at one point (Proof of Lemma 2 on page 14) the calculations become rather obscure, so I gave up. More concretely, given the PDE \begin{align*} &a(x,y,u)u_x+b(x,y,u)u_y=c(x,y,u) \\ &u(f(s),g(s))=h(s), s \in (-\alpha,\alpha)\end{align*} and the characteristic equations \begin{align*}
\dot{x}(t,s)&=a(x,y,z)           &  x(0,s)=f(s)             \\
\dot{y}(t,s)&=b(x,y,z)        &  y(0,s)=g(s) \\
\dot{z}(t,s)&=c(x,y,z)          &  z(0,s)=h(s)
\end{align*}
I want to know about depence (continuity, differentiability) of solutions of the characteristic equations on $t$ and especially on $s$.

Comment: Have you read Evans' ['Partial Differential Equations'](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=evans+partial+differential+equations)? Also, you say you want to understand the ideas behind existence and uniqueness, but then when you have notes that present said ideas you give up, so I'm not sure what you're after.

Comment: You are right, I blew it, I'll change my question, but too late now. Evans is bog-standard on the method of characteristics. I wanted as much references as possible, surely I'm not the only one that ever wondered about it. The text in my link is excellent, however I don't understand the proof of the key lemma, so I understand nothing (looks very dodgy, mistake?)